# FQL: How to get "likes a link" data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the posts on user's stream of type: " likes a link".
I have the "read_stream" permissions and I can't see those kind of status updates.

I know about the "url_like" table (which gives the URL which the user liked), using this table I get the relevant posts I want.
My problem is that the "url_like" table has only 2 fields (user_id, url) and I can't figure out how to get the DATA about this url (the post_id which got the LIKE)

The post_id will help me get the DATA about that post (same data which is displayed in the real facebook stream - showing the original post which the user liked)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want to get all required data via fql.  But i think you should use Grap Api like in below ;

[Likes Information](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/likes?fields=links)

For detailed information about like, you should use EDGE module like in below link;

[Detailed Like Info](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/likes?fields=posts)

You should inject that prefix into the your code like (ex. PHP)

// Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        try {
             // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
             $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
             error_log($e);
              $user = null;
           }
}

and see how result will be look like.

```
<?php  #print_r($user_profile); ?>
```